# Sorting associated column in table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try doing sortable column based on [228 Sortable Table Columns](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns)

Everything is correct, but I don't have idea how to sort associated column with another model.

```
# Table name: vacations
#  id        :integer          not null, primary key
#  start_at  :date             not null
#  end_at    :date             not null
#  person_id :integer          not null
```

I tried using this:

```
  = sortable "person.first_name", "Employee"
```

This not work correct.

Associations

```
class Vacation < ActiveRecord::Base   
belongs_to :person 
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :vacations
end
```

Schema of people table:

```
# Table name: people
#
#  id                         :integer          not null, primary key
#  pesel                      :string           not null
#  first_name                 :string           not null
#  last_name                  :string           not null
```

Current index action in **VacationsController**.

```
def index
    @vacations = Vacation.order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction)
                         .paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
end
```

Sorting methods.

```
  def sort_column
    Vacation.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : 'start_at'
  end

  def sort_direction
    %w(asc desc).include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : 'asc'
  end
```

Update:

```
Vacation.joins(:person).column_names
```

returns:

```
=> ["id", "start_at", "end_at", "free", "reason", "person_id", "accepted"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are following guides from the RailsCast, you should have some code like:

```
@vocations = Vocation.order(params[:sort] + ' ' + params[:direction])
```

And if you would like to sort by column in another model, which in your case `Person` model, you have to update your query to join your `people` table to make it work.

```
@vocations = Vocation.includes(:person).order(params[:sort] + ' ' + params[:direction]).references(:people)
```

In you view,

```
= sortable "people.first_name", "Employee"
```

UPDATE:

You could update your `sort_column` to handle the special case for your joined table:

```
  JOINED_TABLE_COLUMNS = %w(people.first_name)
  def sort_column
    if JOINED_TABLE_COLUMNS.include?(params[:sort]) || Vacation.column_names.include?(params[:sort])
      params[:sort]
    else
      'start_at
    end
  end
```

Comment: your method doesn't resolve problem. Url looks like: ?direction=asc&sort=people.first_name

Comment: @ŁukaszKorol Your `sort_columns` method won't return `people.first_name` since it's not included in `Vacation.column_names`.

Comment: If you want `people.first_name` work, make sure that `sort_columns` column will return it back, in your current implementation, it will only return `start_at`.

Comment: Vacation.joins(:person).column_names.include?(params[:sort]) returns false. params[:sort] = 'people.first_name'. Do you know why return false?

Comment: Because `Vacation.joins(:person).column_names` won't return joined table's columns. It will only contain columns in its own table `vocations`.

Comment: @LarrtLv method sort_columns still returns start_at, when it's sort=people.first_name

Comment: How does the new method look like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115036/discussion-between-lukasz-korol-and-larry-lv).

Answer (score -1):

I think you should be able to resolve that with:

```
 = sortable "persons.first_name", "Employee"
```